# find n primes using R

Tags: r

I am trying to find first n primes. I wrote the following function but I am not getting the proper output. I just started out with R, so please ignore the style of programming. :(

```
 function(n){
      primeList<- numeric(0)
      j <- 1
      while(j < n){
        for(i in 1:n){
          if (isprime(i)==2){
            primeList[j]<- i
            print(primeList[j])
            j <- j + 1                  
          }

        }                     
      }

    }
```

Output:
if i need 10 primes.. the program's output is:

```
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 7
```

Comment: How will `i` or `j` ever get above 10 in your code?  and where did you get the function `isprime`?

Comment: gmp library. I am sorry to forgot to mention that in the code

Comment: This is silly:  there are lists of primes, but more to the point, "isprime" is doing the work.  If you want to learn something, write your own prime sieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `for(i in 1:n)` means to check only the first ten numbers (i.e. `1:10`). There's really no reason to have `for(i in 1:n)`, it should just be:

```
while(j < n)
{
    if (isprime(i)==2) ## This is kinda misleading - should return TRUE/FALSE right?
    {
        primeList[j] = i
        j = j + 1
    }
}
```

But more importantly, the documentation for `isprime` (I'd recommend reading it) has a much better way to do what you're doing:

```
# All primes numbers from 1 to 100
t <- isprime(1:99)
(1:99)[t > 0]
```